# Azure DevOps - Pipeline Release Task to Restore Database

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, database-restore

Is there a task in the Release Pipelines of Azure DevOps (either created by Microsoft or 3rd party) that would be able to connect to my database and execute a stored procedure I have that will restore my database?

Currently, I have to remote desktop into my virtual machine that houses my SQL Server 2019 database and execute my restore script.  What I'd like to do is have a task that will access my database in my VM and restore it for me, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that or even if that functionality exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there are no available [pre-defined tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/?view=azure-devops) to execute sql script in SQL Server database in Azure pipelines.

As a workaround, you could try to [deploy self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#install) on your VM, and then use this agent in release pipeline, so the release will run on your VM. And you could run your sql script using the [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) or [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops). See: [Custom Azure DevOps pipeline task to execute a SQL script](https://careers.centric.eu/nl/blog/net-development/custom-azure-devops-pipeline-task-execute-sql-script/) for more details.

BTW, we find this 3rd-party extension: [SQLplus Executer - Release Edition](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ATP.ATP-SQLplusExecuter-Release), which can execute sql-files using SQLplus. You might check it.

Comment: Hi Tscott, How about this issue? Please check my answer and kindly let me know the result.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this and see if it works for me.

Comment: If there is any update, please let me know. Thanks.